# Having problem while scraping playstore reviews

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

When I inspect the HTML element, to get the reviews from the play store `span tag` with the class name *`X43Kjb`*.  However, I am getting an empty string.

```
url = "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cashkaro&showAllReviews=true"
import requests                
rom bs4 import BeautifulSoup                  
response = requests.get(url)                          
doc = BeautifulSoup(page_contents, 'html.parser')                      
span_tags = doc.find_all('span', {'class' : "X43Kjb"})                         
len(span_tags)
```

Output: `0`

Answer (score 0):

Playstore uses `javascript` to load data. So, I don't think you can scrape it just using`requests` and `BeautifulSoup`. But if you try to analyse deeply then your may found data just using, these library.

I have found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68441842/when-i-inspect-the-html-element-to-get-the-reviews-from-play-store-span-tag-wit) answer, it may or may not work for you but give it a try. This is also example how deeply you have to analyse website html code to find data there.

```
import urllib,json,requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
URL='http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.delta.mobile.android&hl=en_US&showAllReviews=true'
USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.14; rv:65.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/65.0"
headers = {"user-agent": USER_AGENT}
resp = requests.get(URL, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.content, "html.parser")
#print(soup.prettify())
a=[]
txt = soup.find_all('script',text=True)
for i in txt:
    if("gp:" in i.text):
        a.append(i.text)
i=a[-1]
i=i.split(",null,\"")
del i[0]
for j in i:
    if('http' not in j):
        print(j[:j.index("\"")])
        print()
```

***Disclaimer: I had not tested this piece of code. So, it may work or not I don't know.***

Anyway, I am suggesting you to use [`selenium`](https://pypi.org/project/selenium) for scraping data from these types of websites, which loads data using `javascript`.